# Given a string, return a string where for every char is the original, there are two chars?

Tags: java, string

I want to print out every string twice backwards for example (string -> ggnniirrttss)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReverseDoubleChar {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string ");
    String str = input.nextLine();
    String new_str = "";

             String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        result += str.substring(i, i + 1) + str.substring(i, i + 1);
        String result2 = null;
        result2 = result;
        System.out.println(result2);
        }
    }
}
```

Yet when I enter this code all I get is

```
ss
tt
rr
ii
nn
gg
```

all on new lines. Anybody know how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Change `println` to `print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments on the lines I changed:

1. Iterate the string backwards
2. Don't print each double char in each loop iteration since you are concatenating the final result
3. Print the final result after the loop

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class ReverseDoubleChar {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a string ");
   String str = input.nextLine();
   String new_str = "";

   String result = "";
   for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { //Iterate through string backwards
       result += str.substring(i, i + 1) + str.substring(i, i + 1); //Concatenation
       String result2 = null;
       result2 = result;
       // System.out.println(result2); //Don't print each double char since you're concatenating above
   }
   System.out.println(result); //Print full double-charred string after loop
   }

   }
   ```

Output:

```
Enter a string 
string
ggnniirrttss
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the for loop iterate backwards:

```
String result = "";
for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    String s = str.substring(i, i + 1);
    result += s + s;
}

System.out.println(result);
```

or with a forwards loop:

```
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    String s = str.substring(i, i + 1);
    result = s + s + result;
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a StringBuilder instead of doing your own substring and concatenations.

```
public class ReverseDoubleChar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string ");
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(input.nextLine());        
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            result.append(str.charAt(i));
            result.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String result="";
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
result=result+str.charAt(i)+ str.charAt(i);
}
return result;
```

This code works fine.